# Simple instance of borel set and topology set

Tags: real-analysis, borel-sets

To understand topology set and borel set and open set I need some ￼concrete instance. 
Suppose $X=\left[0,1\right],A=\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$, what is the smallest topology and Borel sigma algebra contains A in X?

Comment: What do you mean by a topology set? $A$ is clearly Borel since it is the complement of a open set $({1 \over 2},1]$.

Comment: I am not sure what's your question. But the smallest topology $\mathcal{T}$ containing $A$ in $X$ is $\{\phi,X,A\}$.

Comment: The set $A$ is not an element of the usual topology.

Comment: That's why I need a instance, you can point out my mistake on question, and help me to correct it and give a concrete answer..There are too many  abstract explanations but less concrete one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a bit clarification. First, note that given a set $X$, a topology $\tau$ on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $A$ satisfying the following three axioms:

- $\emptyset \in \tau$
- For any collection $\{A_{\alpha}\}$ in $\tau$, $\bigcup_{\alpha}A_{\alpha}\in \tau$
- For any finite collection $\{A_1,\dots,A_n\}\subset \tau$, $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i \in \tau$.

Note that, we 'define' members of topology to be open sets with respect to this particular topology.

A sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$, is another collection of subsets of $X$, which satisfies

- $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{F}$
- For every $X \in \mathcal{F}$, $X^c \in \mathcal{F}$
- For a countable collection $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\in\mathcal{F}$, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\in\mathcal{F}$.

Next, we will define Borel sigma algebra. Given any set $X$ and a topology $\tau$, the Borel sigma algebra is the smallest sigma algebra containing all members of the topology $\tau$. We call members of Borel $\sigma-$algebra as Borel sets.

Given this, the smallest topology containing $A$ is $\{\emptyset, X, A\}$; and the corresponding Borel sigma algebra is $\{\emptyset, X , A, A^c\}$.

Comment: The definition of borel set says that all the open set in topology space, but $A=\left[ 0,\frac{1}{2} \right]$ is a closed set, is it a problem?That's my confusion.

Comment: So, definition of openness really depends on the particular topology that we are considering. Recall, topology is a collection of subsets of a given set, satisfying the axioms above. Members of topology are precisely what is known as 'open' sets (the intuition that you have, $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ being closed, is a fact from metric topology, but for instance if you take your topology to be the power set, where every set is defined as open, it turns out to be open, with respect to this new, what is known as discrete topology).

Comment: So borel sigma algebra is  $\{\emptyset,\left[0,1\right],\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right),\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right] \}$? @Aaron

Comment: Yes. Note that, the inclusion $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ is necessary, due to second axiom of sigma algebra above.

Comment: I made a misunderstanding on "every open set" as "all sub sets are open set", that's confuse me a lot...

Comment: Are you satisfied, or need clarification man? So, we take a topology, and call its members as our 'open' sets. 

One trivial topology, is the one where we include all subsets. With respect to this topology, all subsets are open.

Yet another extreme, consider another topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$ (aka indiscrete topology). Under this topology, only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$ itself.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, it helps me a lot.@Aaron